# Running selenium with Firefox and getting XCOMP error

Tags: python, docker, selenium, firefox

Below is the scripts i use -

```
#dockerimage = python
before_script:
    - wget --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US'
    - tar -C /opt -xjf /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2
    - rm /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2
    - ln -fs /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
    - git clone <repo>
    - pip install -r <requirement>
    - wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.1/geckodriver-v0.29.1-linux64.tar.gz
    - tar -xvzf  geckodriver-v0.29.1-linux64.tar.gz -C ./uitests/ui_test_suite/
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install unzip xvfb
  script:
    - '# --- print env variables ---------------------------------------------'
    - printenv | grep -E "^(APP_|CORE_|JOB_|STACK_)" | sort
    - '# --- run tests -------------------------------------------------------'
    - xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1920x1080x24" pytest ./ui_test_suite/tests --html=ui_test_report.html --self-contained-html --tb=short  --run_type=firefox
```

Attaching Error as well.

Please help with this.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoGhi.jpg)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: Have added the error as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue using the below imports.

> - apt-get -y install --reinstall libdbus-glib-1-2
> - apt-get -y install packagekit-gtk3-module